# What does (TYPE_TAB_POINT : = TYPE_TAB_POINT();) mean in Oracle PL/SQL?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

What does `TYPE_TAB_POINT : = TYPE_TAB_POINT();` mean in Oracle PL/SQL ?

And please, can someone explain to me what the following instruction means :

```
vTabPoint(vTabPoint.COUNT) :=
TYPE_POINT(ID_CHRONIQUE=>pIdChronique,HORIZON=>'J'||vCurseur.JOUR);
```

Do we instanciate a tab or something like that ?

What does `||` mean ?

Comment: || means concatenate

Comment: TYPE_TAB_POINT() will be a function declared in your package or as a stand alone function in your schema. I'd look for it there. The || denotes a concatination of a string. So it's make the string "JWED" if the day happens to be wednesday. vTabPoint will be a Tabletype. Like an array. So you're opinting to the index "vTabPoint.COUNT) in your array and setting the value that was returned from calling the function TYPE_POINT. TYPE_POINT is another internal function in the package or in the schema

Comment: Yes exactly, it was a function in my schema. Thanks

Comment: Ok I see. In fact, `vTabPoint.COUNT` is my index like the natural `i` in Java. And vTabPoint is an array of elements, each element being ot type `TYPE_POINT`. So, it just modifies one element of the vTabPoint array. Does `VTabPoint.COUNT` refer to the last element of the array ?

Comment: `VTabPoint.COUNT` is the number of elements in the array, so `vTabPoint(vTabPoint.COUNT)` returns the last element of the array (assuming it is "dense" i.e. there aren't missing indices).